# Why do upvote indicators now have a brown background?

Tags: discussion, bug, design, upvotes, colors

When I upvote a SO question, the upvote indicator background adopts a strong brown color. That didn't use to be the case. Why does brown make sense? Why was this change made? Considering one of the common connotations of round brown things, I was thinking maybe it was April 1st already.
Example:

[image]

Comment: Because the design was changed

Comment: @Zoeisonstrike: How is this a dupe of that? :-(

Comment: @KevinB: That is somewhat of a tautological statement; the design was changed to have brown upvote indicators, the question is - why?

Comment: It's tangentially related, as both came with the same (unannounced) design update

Comment: @einpoklum It's the exact same change, just on dark mode instead of light mode. And again, potentially; I'm not sure if the light mode vs. dark mode distinction is enough for it not to be a dupe

Comment: probably because someone or something indicated the change would be more "accessible"

Comment: The colour is set to be `var(--theme-primary-500)` so it doesn't really depend on which colour mode you use. It's always dependent on the colour scheme for the mode.

Comment: It is a dupe. It was an unannounced design change because it was a bug. Someone is looking at it which is reflected in the other post.

Comment: @Piper you say it's a dup and yet you don't use your mod status to close the dup? just curious- why?

Comment: @starball Devs have mod status by nature of their job, but mostly tend not to use it and allow the community/elected mods/CMs to handle things (they are, of course, welcome to ask mods in our mod room to do things like this if they'd prefer that one of us check that it's the correct action and perform it).

Comment: Why do the giant round buttons make sense? Why is the top-right block yellow? Why does the second hamburger menu icon represent a comic book text bubble? Why in the "learn more about formatting" page is vital information hidden behind a "show more" link with a tiny, tiny font size? Why is help center documentation split up into separate "do" and "don't" pages? Why is answer acceptance represented with a giant "I am going to lie to you and make you think this is the correct answer!" checkmark icon? What is sensibility anyway :)